# I've tried to implement Location Autosuggestions using the example in youtube tutorial, but I get an error

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

[here is the link for the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Trdd9EnmqY),

[this is the link for the sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecomplete/PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.java) ,
 and here is my code:
    `mGoogleApiClient= new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this,this)
                .build();
        mPlaceAdapter=new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this,mGoogleApiClient,LAT_LNG_BOUNDS,null);`

constructor of PlaceAutocompleteAdapter class:

```
public PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, GeoDataClient geoDataClient,
                                LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1);
    mGeoDataClient = geoDataClient;
    mBounds = bounds;
    mPlaceFilter = filter;
}
```

I've have all the imports necessary and the following in my gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

and the error I get :

```
error: incompatible types: GoogleApiClient cannot be converted to GeoDataClient
```

Comment: You need to construct a `GeoDataClient` (for second parameter) - example code does it this way: `mGeoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(this, null);` (where `this` is the activity.

Comment: I've tried this, also won't work.